# How to add values in reducer class into an arraylist (Hadoop)?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

My Mapper output:

```
1504652886  Geography
8904209587  Science
8904209587  Math
9341024668  English9
9341024668  Science
```

I am trying to write a reducer class now that will combine the common keys and generate an output as shown below:

```
1504652886  Geography
8904209587  Science, Math
9341024668  English9, Science
```

In the reducer class, I tried to make an arraylist that will contain all courses for a particular ID but I am surely doing something wrong. My code is as below:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    @Override 
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<String> courses = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Text x : values)
        {
            courses.add((Text) x);
        }
    }      
}
```

But I am missing something and getting error:

```
The method add(String) in the type ArrayList<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Text)
```

Can anybody please advise how to get the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop's `Text` class has a [toString()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#toString%28%29) method that returns a String representation of this object. So could just replace the following in your code:

```
for(Text x : values)
{
    courses.add(x.toString());
}
```

Then, you will need to convert the ArrayList back to Text, however, in order to emit it as a key.

You are also missing the `write()` method, which actually emits the output.

You could use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead, which should be faster than using an ArrayList:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    Text valueToEmit = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Text x : values)
        {
            sb.append(x.toString()).append(",");
        }

        valueToEmit.set(sb.substring(0,sb.length()-1)); //to remove the last ','
        context.write(key, valueToEmit);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much @vefthym! It works perfectly and I understand the code too.